# How to bind multiple observers to one ControlProperty

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I need to bind `slider.rx.value` to 2 observers with different mappings.

```
slider.rx.value.map  { [unowned self] in self.formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: $0)) ?? "" }
    .bindTo(textFieldAlpha.rx.text)
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

slider.rx.value.map { Enhance.Global(alpha: $0) }
    .bindTo(enhance)
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

But i seems that only last binding works. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this accomplish what you want?

```
let observable = slider.rx.value.shareReplay(1)

observable.map  { [unowned self] in self.formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: $0)) ?? "" }
    .bindTo(textFieldAlpha.rx.text)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

observable.map { Enhance.Global(alpha: $0) }
    .bindTo(enhance)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Alternative if you do not need the buffer

```
let observable = slider.rx.value.share()
```

Here is also a link to a nice cheat sheet for RxSwift https://www.cheatography.com/donghua-li/cheat-sheets/rxswift-operators/

Comment: Hm, it was not obvious from documentation that I need `shareReplay(1)` for binding, but it probably because I'm newbie in Rx. Also I don't need replay buffer, so `share()` is enough for me. Thanks!