# UIButton.isSelected can't Observable

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton, rx-swift

I want to check the isSelected state of some UIButtons in order to feed the isEnabled state of another button. I wanted the latter button enabled only when one of the other buttons isSelected state is set to true.
However I saw that you have chosen to keep the isSelected property only as an Observer.

```
@IBAction func checkBoxButtonTaped(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.rx.isSelected.onNext(!sender.isSelected)
}
```

Or

```
@IBAction func checkBoxButtonTaped(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}
```

Observable Code:

```
let state = Observable.just(true)
state.bindTo(checkBoxButton.rx.isSelected)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
state.bindTo(loginButton.rx.isEnabled)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

By two code snippets, Observable can't work.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/40789460/1113632 ? I am not 100% sure that I understand your question

Comment: @KaraBenNemsi thanks, but `ControlProperty` can work, `button.rx.isSelected` is a UIBindingObserver not work.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can simply use scan:

```
checkBoxButton.rx.tap
    .scan(false) { lastValue, _ in
        return !lastValue
    }
    .bind(to: loginButton.rx.isEnabled)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

[Here](http://rx-marin.com/post/rxswift-state-with-scan/) is a more detailed explanation of how scan works.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you took outlet for the another button which you want to set enabled/disabled. And set enabled property in target buttion action something like

```
@IBAction func checkBoxButtonTaped(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    btnTarget.enabled = sender.isSelected
}
```

Comment: I want use RxSwift to control state.

Comment: I apologize for that as I did not work with Rxswift... Happy coding.

Comment: Can you please help me to learn Rxswift, I have started to learn basics of it. Can you please share good links of it. So i may refer them.

Comment: [https://www.raywenderlich.com/158026/introducing-rxswift-reactive-programming-swift](https://www.raywenderlich.com/158026/introducing-rxswift-reactive-programming-swift)

Comment: [https://www.raywenderlich.com/138547/getting-started-with-rxswift-and-rxcocoa](https://www.raywenderlich.com/138547/getting-started-with-rxswift-and-rxcocoa)

Comment: [https://store.raywenderlich.com/products/rxswift](https://store.raywenderlich.com/products/rxswift)

Answer (score -1):

I find a way to solve by `Variable`:

```
let checkBoxValid = Variable(true)
_ = checkBoxValid.asObservable().bindTo(checkBoxButton.rx.isSelected)

_ = checkBoxButton.rx.tap.subscribe(onNext: {
    checkBoxValid.value = !checkBoxValid.value
})
```